# How to control XmlElement name for array of string items in Xml document when generating Xml from XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I am using XmlSerializer class to serialize object into xml file and transfer over wire.
I have created following data structure which contents data and transfer over wire.

```
 [Serializable]
 public class MailItem
{
    public string UniqueEmailId { get; set; }
    public string SenderEmailId { get; set; }
    public string[] ToRecipientEmailId { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I am converting to xml it emits following result –

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MailItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UniqueEmailId>SomeUniqueID</UniqueEmailId>
  <SenderEmailId>sender@email.id</SenderEmailId>
  <ToRecipientEmailId>
    <string>To@email.id</string>
    <string>To1@email.id</string>
    <string>To2@email.id</string>
  </ToRecipientEmailId>  
</MailItem>
```

Expected result is (observe child elements of ToRecipientEmailId) –

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MailItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UniqueEmailId>SomeUniqueID</UniqueEmailId>
  <SenderEmailId>sender@email.id</SenderEmailId>
  <ToRecipientEmailId>
    <EmailId>To@email.id</EmailId>
    <EmailId>To1@email.id</EmailId>
    <EmailId>To2@email.id</EmailId>
  </ToRecipientEmailId>  
</MailItem>
```

When I created another class with Email and EmailId as property into it then it gives me following result –

```
[Serializable]
     public class MailItem
    {
        public string UniqueEmailId { get; set; }
        public string SenderEmailId { get; set; }
        public List<Email> ToRecipientEmailId { get; set; }
    }         

   public class Email
    {
        public string EmailID {get;set;}
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MailItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UniqueEmailId>SomeUniqueID</UniqueEmailId>
  <SenderEmailId>sender@email.id</SenderEmailId>
  <ToRecipientEmailId>
    <Email>
      <EmailID>To@email.id</EmailID>
    </Email>
    <Email>
      <EmailID>To1@email.id</EmailID>
    </Email>
    <Email>
      <EmailID>To2@email.id</EmailID>
    </Email>
  </ToRecipientEmailId> 
</MailItem>
```

It would be great if someone let me know how to achieve desired result. What changes I need to make in data structure ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`[XmlArrayItem(elementName)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1d071w8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to specify the element names to be used for array entries:

```
public class MailItem
{
    public string UniqueEmailId { get; set; }
    public string SenderEmailId { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem("EmailId")]
    public string[] ToRecipientEmailId { get; set; }
}
```

Note you don't need the `[Serializable]` attribute, that is used for binary serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Don't use XmlArrayItem is will create an extra tag layer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("MailItem")]
    public class MailItem
    {
        [XmlElement("UniqueEmailId")]
        public string UniqueEmailId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("SenderEmailId")]
        public string SenderEmailId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ToRecipientEmailId")]
        public string[] ToRecipientEmailId { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: @jdweng- it creates multiple <ToRecipientEmailId> elements instead of creating parent child relationship between <ToRecipientEmailId>  and <EmailId>